# sum/merge multiple data source in google data studio

Tags: data-visualization, looker-studio

I have added 5 google ad data sources to my dashboard. I want to merge them all together. I tried to blend the data. But for each dataset, it takes its own metrics. As a result, I am getting individual metrics for each of them like 5 different "Link Clicks". But how can I combine/merge them together? Is there any functionality or I need to write some code for summing up the metrics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Data Studio doesn't allow merging columns from different data sources.

Data Blending operation lets you blend different data sources and use them for the charts. The possible way could be creating new fields but there's no way to add custom fields in blended data. The only way here could be using formulas in charts to sum up the data. Like you will have `Link_Clicks_A`, `Link_Clicks_B` etc. You can sum them up.

1. SUM: Try using the sum function

   `SUM(Link_Clicks_A) + SUM(Link_Clicks_B) + SUM(Link_Clicks_C)`
2. NARY_MAX: If the sum function doesn't work, you could try this one.

   `NARY_MAX(Link_Clicks_A, 0) + NARY_MAX(Link_Clicks_B, 0) + NARY_MAX(Link_Clicks_C, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are in the correct path.

Just blend your data as you already did.  Doing this, you'll have 5 fields with the same information, one from each data source (like `link_clicks_sourceA`, `link_clicks_sourceB` etc).

Then, create a new field in this blended source called `blended_link_clicks` with this formula (the field should be created in the chart level, since there's no way to add custom fields in a blended data source):

```
CASE
  WHEN link_clicks_sourceA IS NOT NULL THEN link_clicks_sourceA
  WHEN link_clicks_sourceB IS NOT NULL THEN link_clicks_sourceB
  WHEN link_clicks_sourceC IS NOT NULL THEN link_clicks_sourceC
  WHEN link_clicks_sourceD IS NOT NULL THEN link_clicks_sourceD
  WHEN link_clicks_sourceE IS NOT NULL THEN link_clicks_sourceE
  ELSE NULL
END
```

PS: For some reason, I tried to reproduce the steps here before posting and, in fact, this solution didn't work.  In my tests, the expression `anyField IS NOT NULL` always evaluates to `false` in CASE statements and I don't know why.  I would say this is due to a bug in DataStudio, so I decided to post the answer anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I also tried the same. The only thing I could do is summing up the metric values using the nary_max function: 

`NARY_MAX(Link_Clicks_A, 0) + NARY_MAX(Link_Clicks_B, 0) + NARY_MAX(Link_Clicks_C, 0)`